# Giving values to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to give "data" within "drilldown" some values.  But i keep getting an error message that "data.drilldown" is not defined". What am i doing wong? It has something to do with the syntax on the last row in the code below. I have tried a dozen different options to define data.drilldown.data but i dont find the right solution.

Plz give me some help :)

Br.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [

                {
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data: [{}],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                },

                {
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data: [{}],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }


                ];

    var url =  "php/live-server-data.php?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url,  function(data) {




    *data.drilldown.data = data;*

    });
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is an Array.

You need to access the first element in the Array:

```
data[0].drilldown
```

That is, if you are referring to the object in the first part of your code.
If you are really looking at the data coming back from the service, there's no way we can now as that is data that's coming back and it might be anything